# How to get value from radio button if using jsp scriplet

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a form with radio button and the value is get from database. below is code in my form. btw this form is for survey question.

```
for(int i=0; i<qlist.size(); i++){
//question loop
for(int j=0; j<alist.size(); j++){
//answer loop
    <input type="radio" name="radio_<%=j%>" value="<%= alist.getAnswerDesc()%>"
    <input type="radio" name="radio_<%=j%>" value="<%= alist.getAnswerDesc()%>"
    }
}
```

in servlet im using below code to get values of the radio button.

```
for(int i=0; i<qlist.size(); i++{
   for(int j=0; j<alist.size(); j++{
      String radio = request.getParameter("radio_"+j);
   }
}
```

But i cant get value. Help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: you have a name for the radio button??

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will extract values from database to radio button values,

```
<%
// add code for connection here

Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
ResultSet Rs = null;
Rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select column_name from table_name ");
int i=1;%>
<%while(Rs.next()){
%>

<tr><td><input type="radio" value="<%=Rs.getString("column_name")%>" name="radio<%=i%>"/><%=Rs.getString("column_name")%></td></tr>
<%
i++;
}
%>
```